# Confused on how to efficiently loop thru the correct folders

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

So i have a need to loop thru set of specific folders on our network looking for files and creating new folder with found files. 
So we have a folder where we back up files daily/weekly for processing by a certain department. The Folders start off as the YEAR, then DATE and then all the files for that given date

```
Example:
c:\backup\2018
       c:\backup\2018\06-06-2018\
c:\backup\2019
       c:\backup\2019\09-20-2019\
c:\backup\2020
       c:\backup\2020\02-20-2020\
```

So my application i'm building get a MAX date/year from the previous year folder and then builds a new folder with everything GREATER than that year

So if i go into my c:\backup\ folder there will be in this example 2018, 2019, 2020
within each year there is a folder for each day files were backed up.

Now if my application determines that the MAX date from the last time we processed was 8/6/2019
I need to loop thru ONLY the 2019 and 2020 folders, find any date folder that is greater than 8/6/2019 and copy each file within each date into the appropriate new folder.

My first attempt was to loop thru the backup folder for the year folder that is the same, but my confusion is how can i efficiently loop thru all 2019 folders and move on to 2020 folder, since that is greater than 8/6/2019 as well. Once i got into the 2019, processing those were quick, but how to code that logic so it knows to jump into the 2020 root folder and continue the processing?

Attached is a visual of the folder structure so its a little more clear

[image]

Here is the current code that seems to work but some how in a infinite loop :( 
The brgDirs are the root directories (2019 and 2020)
The fldF contains the max date for each type of file im looking for
The sdD contains all the date folder names ( 08-07-2019, etc..)

```
    foreach (DirectoryInfo b in brgDirs)
    {
        int bd = Convert.ToInt32(b.Name);
        DateTime bdt = new DateTime(bd, 1, 1);
        foreach(Wave w in fldF)
        {
            int wd = Convert.ToInt32(w.MYEAR);
            DateTime wdt = new DateTime(wd, 1, 1);
            if (wdt >= bdt)
            {
                DirectoryInfo[] sdD = b.GetDirectories();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo sd in sdD)
                {
                    DateTime pWDate = DateTime.Parse(w.MDATE);
                    DateTime pSDate = DateTime.Parse(sd.Name);                            
                    if(pSDate.Date > pWDate.Date)
                    {
                        ProcessEachFolder(sd.FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And im handling the Processing of each file in this method

```
private void ProcessEachFolder(string fpath)
{
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(fpath);  // WAVE SUBFOLDER FOLDER PATH
    waveDirectory = @"C:\backup\Test\" + currentWave;

    foreach (string d in fileEntries)
    {
        string fileNAME = Path.GetFileName(d);
        if (d.Contains("CLEARANCE_MOD"))
        {
            File.Copy(d, waveDirectory + @"\CLR\" + fileNAME, true);
        }
        if (d.Contains("DEALS_MOD"))
        {
            File.Copy(d, waveDirectory + @"\HD\" + fileNAME, true);
        }
        if (d.Contains("DROP_MOD"))
        {
            File.Copy(d, waveDirectory + @"\PD\" + fileNAME, true);
        }
        if (d.Contains("LABELS_MOD"))
        {
            File.Copy(d, waveDirectory + @"\UPL\" + fileNAME, true);
        }

    }
}
```

After the first run, and seeing files populate in the correct folders, i stopped the application, but then i ran it again without breakpoints and let it run and it kept running and running.. and it never hits the foreach (DirectoryInfo b in brgDirs) again, its processing the same folders and files over and over and wont jump to the next folder which is the 2020 folder.

```
List<Wave> fldF = new List<Wave>();

private class Wave
{
    public string FLD { get; set; }
    public string MDATE { get; set; }
    public string MYEAR { get; set; }
}
```

Values within fldF currently are like so

```
FLD = CL, MDATE = 08-06-2019, MYEAR = 2019
FLD = HD, MDATE = 08-06-2019, MYEAR = 2019
FLD = PD, MDATE = 08-01-2019, MYEAR = 2019
FLD = UP, MDATE = 08-06-2019, MYEAR = 2019
```

Comment: You could create a list of dates greater than 08/06/19 and then create a list of folders from that list and search for all folders that exist. that way you get a list of folders that exists and have date greater than 08/06/19.

Comment: How do you determine the last date you've processed? By checking the destination location folders?

Comment: So the files within the date folder are names with the datetime, im parsing that file name to get the max date from the last time we processed. Right now this is all a manual process, someone creates a new "processed" folder, looks at the last processed folder to determine when they ran it last, then copy any new files since then into the new folder. From there they do whatever they do with the files/data. But its a long process for someone to go look in each folder and copy and paste into a new folder.

Comment: @Sebastian Siemens if the folders im going to loop thru are already a list of dates, why would i need to create a list of them? Just want to understand your suggestion.

Comment: Is it ok for an answer to abstract the latest processed date finding process like `GetLastProcessedDate()` ? Because there is not enough information (no concrete path, folder names etc.) for that process?

Comment: I think you should post your code.

Comment: Does the source and destination folders have the exact same structure? Like; c:\backup and c:\processed both have yyyy folders for years and under these mm-dd-yyyy folders for the files for that date?

Comment: Found where the loop is occurring, so thats not an issue any more, BUT because of how i was looping thru the List<Wave> if i remove that loop, then i cant process the folders. based on the code i provided, can anyone see how i can improve the overall process?

Comment: @Oguz Ozgul as for the folder structure, no they do not. Source is the Year\Date\File structure   and the destination is Wave\subfolder\files (subfolders here are 1 of 4 possibilities)

Comment: I created the exact same folder hierarchies and run your code and did not see any problems. It processed the 2019 folders then moved on to 2020. There some variables used in your code which I can't see how populated. Can you please post the full class? I think the problem is that you don't update the fldF to contain the newly processed dates and that's why it's looping infinitely, but to be sure, I must see the whole class.

Comment: I just posted the information as well as example data that is populated in the List<Wave> the more i look at it, the more i think i should be looping thru that list later on once im already down in the sub folders and not before that, because it would loop thru it 4 times every time we run the process.

Answer (score 0):

So after a day of trial and error, i found a solution that seems to work. Taking the suggestions above, i build a List of all paths found in the sub directories, then i loop thru that entire list and do my check and validation for files i need and then execute the copy to the new destination folder. First 2 test runs look correct and successful. Next im going to throw some weird files and directory names to see if my error handling works.

I really appreciate the suggestions. Although ill probably create a new question, i need to find a way to grab the earliest "year" from my class, right now i have this line

```
var distinctyear = fldF.Select(x => x.MYEAR).Distinct();
```

But this test was with a small simple set of files and folders. So i need to make sure that if there are more than one year in that list(fldF) that i need to get the oldest only from it to set my variable

In this test, fldF had "2019" and "2020" and for this one i would want "2019"

The is always a chance that there will be 2 year values in the list, so i always want to get the oldest one.

thanks again for the help and suggestions.